# .NET 8 adding local timezone to datetime property

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I updated my Web API App from .NET 7 to .NET 8. When I get date values, it adds +5:30 hours to the time values which is my server's time zone. I am using `CodeFirst` with `Postgresql`.

Here is my code

NewtonsoftJson's options in `Startup.cs`

```
 services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
 {
     options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local; // commenting this line returns "2024-01-02T13:11:37.076752Z"
 });
```

and my API is

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<DateTime?> t()
{
    string Con = _configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext");
    MyContext _Context = new(Con);
    var sh = await _Context.MyTable.OrderByDescending(o => o.id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var jsonStringNs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sh.lastUpdatedOn);
    // debug "2024-01-02T13:11:37.076752Z" Correct

    var jsonStringCs = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(sh.lastUpdatedOn);
    // debug "2024-01-02T13:11:37.076752Z" Correct

    return sh.lastUpdatedOn;
}
```

It returns as below

```
"2024-01-02T13:11:37.076752+05:30" --> .NET 7
"2024-01-02T18:41:37.076752+05:30" --> .NET 8
```

Actual data when I view it from `PGAdmin` is `2024-01-02 13:11:37.076752` exactly matches as .NET 7.

It seems that values are converting while making `HTTP response`.

How can I get the date format the same as .NET 7 from .NET 8?

Comment: As a starting point, check the `Kind` of the `DateTime` values to see whether one is `Utc` and one is not.

Comment: Is there a reason you deleted your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77745282/dotnet8-adds-servers-timezone-to-datetime-values) and made a new one?

Comment: @DavidG Stack UI showed that it was `CLOSED`. So, I thought that wouldn't be visible to others.

Comment: Then it's your job to get it reopened.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that the offset is serialized with a `DateTime`. Do you have custom conversion in place?

Comment: @Fildor, No, but `NewtonsoftJson`

Comment: as a rule of thumb, use "UTC" whenever storing or communicating time values, and convert to "Local" whenever displaying times to the user. Note that NpgSql may return DateTimes in "Local" even if they are stored as "UTC", you may need to do manual conversion, or configure settings to change the behavior.

Comment: It seems that values are converting while making `HTTP response`. I added extra debug results in the question.

Comment: Please stop putting things in a code font that aren't code. There is *no* reason for "HTTP response" to be in a code font in the penultimate paragraph, for example. This sort of random formatting makes the question significantly harder to read.

Comment: @JonasH: That's not a good rule of thumb to be propagated without significant caveats, particularly for future values. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/ for details. (In many cases using UTC is fine, but you really need to know about the cases where it's *not* appropriate.)

Comment: Consider  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-8-0